# Using GAM for the first time on species detection data

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I am running a GAM on species detection data for the first time. I would like to see if there is any interaction between time of year and diel period for both male and female of this species. This is my first time using R so I am just looking for input on the following code for a GAM model/ if this is the right model to use?

```r
> m4 <- gam(res_time_sec ~ s(julianday), data=species, method="REML")
> par(mfrow=c(2,2))
> gam.check(m4)
```

when I check the output there is obviously more to the story in terms of explanatory variables but I am just trying to get the basics down first!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You make reference to “diel period” and apparently expect us to both understand that term and also map it to a variable in your formula. I think you might be a bit batty in that notion.

Comment: What's `res_time_sec`? Do you have `julianday` values over the entire year? (If so you should probably consider using a cyclic spline for the julian day term.) Where's the diel variable? You mentioned an interaction but only included a single smooth term - what are you trying to interact with what? As a time can't be negative are you sure that assuming the response is conditionally distributed Gaussian is appropriate? If this is detection data, how are you accounting for detection probabilities?